# VueJS and Axios causing 'error during execution of scheduler flush' and Uncaught (in promise) TypeError

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, asynchronous, axios

So i have been poking my code for a while and found out that this error is caused specifically by this line of code:

```
treeNodes.value = documentStore.convertToTree((await axios.get('/File')).data);
```

First i get warning saying:

```
Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug. Please open an issue at https://new-issue.vuejs.org/?repo=vuejs/core
```

and then i get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentNode')
```

Tried read some older threads but found nothing helpful.

Any ideas?
thanks

Comment: a single line of code is probably not enough context to identify the error in your code - or possibly the bug in vue - Note: it could also be browser specific, does it occur in all browsers, or just Google Chrome / Microsoft Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured it out.
The problem was that i tried to initialize treeNodes before component was mounted.
So i just init it in onMounted and it works fine.